# tweepy 3.5 search geocode returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, geocode

I am trying to get tweets around an specific location using python 3.4 and tweepy 3.5.0. First, I create an api object:

```
>>> api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Then, if I call create with just a query, I get a lot of results:

```
>>> len(api.search('python'))
15
```

However, when I try to use a geocode, I always get an empty list. No matter what query or radius I use:

```
>>> len(api.search('python', geocode='-33.602131, -70.576876, 100000km'))
0
>>> len(api.search(geocode='-33.602131, -70.576876, 100000km'))
0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the problem!
The geocode argument does not allow spaces.
So, by changing the query, I got results again:

```
>>> len(api.search(geocode='-33.602131,-70.576876,100000km'))
15
```